# Using template argument of base class in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

Consider the following situation in C++:

```
template<int n>
class Base { ... };

class Derived3 : public Base<3> {
  // a complicated body, making use of n=3
};

class Derived7 : public Base<7> {
  // a completely different body, making use of n=7
};
```

Inside of the `Derived3` member functions, I would like to explicitly use `n=3`, and inside `Derived7`, `n=7`, without hardcoding the numbers, i.e., still referring to something like a template argument `n`. The following options come to my mind:

1. Also templating the derived classes on `n`, and then using `typedef`. This way, the derived classes know `n`:

   ```
   template<int n>
   class DerivedTemplate3 : public Base<n> { ... };
   typedef DerivedTemplate3<3> Derived3;

   template<int n>
   class DerivedTemplate7 : public Base<n> { ... };
   typedef DerivedTemplate7<7> Derived7;
   ```

   The problem with this is that `DerivedTemplateX` makes sense for nothing but `n=X`, so this feels like abusing the template paradigm.
2. Using a static const member to store `n` in `Base`, and referring to that in the derived classes:

   ```
   template<int n>
   class Base {
   protected:
     static const int nn = n;
     ...
   };

   class Derived3 : public Base<3> {
     // refer to nn=3
   };

   class Derived7 : public Base<7> {
     // refer to nn=7
   };
   ```

   The problem here is that I seemingly can't use the same identifier (`nn` vs. `n`). Also, I'm not sure whether this will allow me to use `nn` as a template argument for members of the derived classes.

So: how can this be implemented in a non-redundant, efficient way? Maybe using some kind of `static const int` as a member somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard practice is to use an uppercase letter for the template parameter, then a static const value in lowercase:

```
template<int N>
class Base {
protected:
  static const int n = N;
  ...
};
```

Then you use the lowercase static const value `n` everywhere - don't use `N` anywhere else.

> Also, I'm not sure whether this will allow me to use nn as a template argument for members of the derived classes.

It is a constant expression and so it can be used as a template argument.

Comment: That's it. One could also use an `enum` to avoid a static member variable.

Comment: Alright, thank you. So my second suggestion actually is standard practice, except for a slightly different naming convention.

Comment: @KarelPetranek Why would you want to avoid a `static const int` member variable?

Comment: `static const int` variable might occupy some memory at runtime if the compiler isn't smart enough. With heavy use of metaprogramming, there can be many copies of the variable. The problem is more a theoretical one though.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
template<int n>
class Base {
protected:
    static const int MyN = n;
};

class Derived3 : public Base<3> {
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << MyN;
    }
};

class Derived7 : public Base<7> {
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << MyN;
    }
};

int main()
{

}
```