# Meaningful names for base class template arguments

Tags: c++

What is the best approach for naming base class non-type arguments as in

```
class Derived : public Base<Argument> {
...
}
```

It would have been great if I could do this:

```
class Derived : public Base<Argument> {
  constexpr static int Argument = 1;
...
}
```

But Argument is not defined during class declaration of Derived yet.

I could use #define, but I would also like to embed this name inside a namespace.

It is explained the following discussion that the standard practice is to

```
template<int N>
class Base {
protected:
  static const int n = N;
  ...
};
```

and use "n" as the meaningful name wherever this value is needed.

[Using template argument of base class in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435710/using-template-argument-of-base-class-in-derived-class)

However ,the value itself looks encrypted in the derived class declaration:

```
class Derived : public Base<whatever value>
```

Is this method the best choice?

Edit: My motivation is to facilitate modification of this Argument in the future for other developers. It would be easier for them to modify the line "BufferSize = 1024" in

```
class MyScreen : public ScreenBase<BufferSize> {
    ... BufferSize = 1024;
```

rather than

```
class MyScreen : public ScreenBase<1024> {
```

Comment: Your purpose is quite mysterious. What are you trying to achieve? And how do you think `class Derived : public Base<Argument> { constexpr static int Argument = 1; /*...*/ };` solves it?

Comment: Encrypted? It's right there in plain sight, not even slightly hidden. If having a value there bothers you maybe an enum could do.

Comment: My motivation is to facilitate modification of this Argument in the future for other developers. It would be easier for them to modify a line , for example " ... BufferSize = 1024 ", rather than ... : public Derived<1024>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard reasoning with fictional names but, if I understand you correctly, you want to have names for template arguments (for example to quickly search & replace them).

I don't think it's a big problem, you can always search each time `Base<T>` is used as a base class (even a plain naive `grep` for `public Base<` will do. Assuming that for some reasons you don't want to do it and that you can't drop templates in favor of a *property* or a ctor parameter then you just need to introduce a named container for your values:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t V>
struct buffer_size : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, V> {};
```

Now your class declaration will be:

```
template<typename S>
struct buffered_stream<S> {
   static constexpr std::size_t size = S::value;
};
```

Now when you use it you can have a clear understanding of what the parameter is:

```
struct network_stream : public buffered_stream<buffer_size<1024>> {
   // ...
};
```

Note that this is somehow inspired by the approach for templates instantiation you can see, for example, in `std::chrono::duration`. For the same reason you should also consider to use user-defined suffixes (when they're clear enough). For example this might be enough in many cases:

```
struct network_stream : public buffered_stream<1024_bytes> {
   // ...
};
```

---

Please consider this code as a starting point, surely you want to use `std::is_same()` to produce some decent compiler diagnostics (especially if you have more than one *named* argument). This alone will make your code much more complicate than this proof of concept but I suppose you now understand how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Adriano, this pretty much answers my question.